# Is this neutral age screen implementation correct?

Tags: android, admob, google-play-console

According to the official Play Console website, a Neutral Age Screen must be implemented in an app so that the ads that are shown are suitable for that children. This is what it is said by Play Console:

> A neutral age screen is a mechanism to verify a user's age in a way
> that doesn't encourage them to falsify their age and gain access to
> areas of your app that aren't designed for children, for example, an
> age gate. An example of this would be a system that asks users to
> freely enter their month, day, and year of birth. An incorrect setup
> of a neutral age screen would be presetting the birth date to the
> required age (for example, 13 years old) or indicating that a certain
> age is required to access areas of the app. Additional guidance on age
> screens may be found on the FTC website.

Okay, If I have understood it correctly, asking the birthdate should be enough to accomplish Neutral Age Screen, right?

Now that we have obtained the age of the user thanks to the birthdate, I have thought of making the following:

```
if(age >= 18){
 adRequestBuilder.setMaxAdContentRating(MAX_AD_CONTENT_RATING_MA);
}
else if(age >= 12){
 adRequestBuilder.setMaxAdContentRating(MAX_AD_CONTENT_RATING_T);
}
else if(age >= 7){
 adRequestBuilder.setMaxAdContentRating(MAX_AD_CONTENT_RATING_PG);
}
else{
 adRequestBuilder.setMaxAdContentRating(MAX_AD_CONTENT_RATING_G);
}
```

Is that okay?

Answer (score 0):

The layout is also important. For example, I got rejected for [such a design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3gGtQ.png). It seems that because of the "red buttons".